# JavaScript to trim started 0 in a string

Tags: javascript

I hava a time string,the format is HHMM, I need to get the decimal of it, how can I do ?

e.g.

'1221'=1221

'0101'=101

'0011'=11

'0001'=1

If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)

If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal).

But I want to treat it as decimal no matter whether started with 0 or 00 or 000.

---

additional:

thanks all.

I had know what you said, what make I confused as following :

var temp1=0300;
var temp2='0300';

parseInt(temp1,10)=192;
parseInt(temp1,10)=300;

so I I doubt parseInt() and have this question .

Comment: Ahh. I think I understand. "temp1" is a number declared as base8. parseInt does nothing to it because it's a number. 0300==192. However, temp2 is a string and the leading 0 is ignored because you've forced it to parse as base10.

Comment: Your question no longer makes sense. Please update it--as it is now; it's no use to anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) and specify the radix yourself.

```
parseInt("10")     // 10
parseInt("10", 10) // 10
parseInt("010")    //  8
parseInt("10", 8)  //  8
parseInt("0x10")   // 16
parseInt("10", 16) // 16
```

*Note: You should always supply the optional radix parameter, since parseInt will try to figure it out by itself, if it's not provided. This can lead to some very weird behavior.*

**Update:**

This is a bit of a hack. But try using a `String` object:

```
var s = "0300";

parseInt(s, 10); // 300
```

The down-side of this hack is that you need to specify a string-variable. None of the following examples will work:

```
parseInt(0300 + "", 10);              // 192    
parseInt(0300.toString(), 10);        // 192    
parseInt(Number(0300).toString(), 10) // 192
```

Comment: I would rather say: You *need* to specify the radix.

Comment: @Gumbo - except of course that isn't true ;P You *should* specify the radix.

Comment: @Gumbo & annakata: You are right. If you do not parse in the radix the function tries to figure it out by itself. Which can cause some very weird behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep it as a string, you can use regex:

```
num = num.replace(/^0*/, "");
```

If you want to turn it unto a number roosteronacid has the right code.

Comment: thanks.

I had know what you said, what make I confused as following :

var temp1=0300; 
var temp2='0300';

parseInt(temp1,10)=192; 
parseInt(temp1,10)=300;

so I I doubt parseInt() and have this question .

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the radix parameter to [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseInt):

```
var x = '0123';
x = parseInt(x, 10); // x == 123
```

Comment: In this case need to be careful with radix parameter, it's results may be unexpected: parseInt('0x300', 16); => 768 parseInt('0x300', 8); => 0

Answer (score 0):

```
Number("0300") = Number(0300) = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution here:

```
function parse_int(num) {
    var radix = 10;
    if (num.charAt(0) === '0') {
        switch (num.charAt(1)) {
        case 'x':
            radix = 16;
            break;
        case '0':
            radix = 10;
            break;
        default:
            radix = 8;
            break;
    }
    return parseInt(num, radix);
}
var num8 = '0300';
var num16 = '0x300';
var num10 = '300';
parse_int(num8);  // 192
parse_int(num16); // 768
parse_int(num10); // 300
```